# Forcing users to Enter Meta Data on upload/ file creation

Tags: metadata, modern-document-library

We are working with different libraries to store documents for customer projects in the office.

Now I am looking for a way to organize the files and force users to enter metadata information when uploading documents to the Sharepoint libraries or when creating new files.

From my research I understand that there are several ways to solve the tasks but I did not manage to find a proper solution only. Can someone give explain a good way to solve that issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions but each one has its pros and cons. I am assuming you are using SharePoint Online.

In short: this is a challenge: users do not like to set metadata. It takes their time and often they do not see the benefit. Make sure you keep the number of metadata fields to an absolute minimum. Plus the OOTB tools available are not well suited.

Some approaches you may want to consider are:
a. Use the Modern view and educate your users to specify the missing metadata after uploading. This takes a lot of discipline. In most organizations this is too much asked.
b. Use "Column default settings" for folders to ensure documents uploaded into folders "inherit" the proper metadata for that folders. E.g. inherit a project name. It is limited in functionality.
c. Use 3rd party apps. See [list](https://collab365.com/best-document-management-solutions-for-sharepoint/)
This list also includes browser-based apps that support addin metadata during uploading. This includes both setting custom metadata (e.g. customer name) and extracting properties from the files being uploaded (e.g. subject from emails, keywords from pdf files, GPS location from jpg files, ...).
d. Use PowerAutomate to force the user to set metadata

Another thing to be aware off. Even if users start adding metadata from day 1 there are probably lots of existing documents without metadata. This may reduce the effectiveness of adding metadata for new documents. This is something to be aware off. There are tools that can be used to deal with this backlog but that is a separate challenge.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback! 
Is there any chance that you have a reference for a PowerAutomate solution approach?

Comment: Welcome. Not at hand. I prefer to use REST API to address these kind of challenges. Hopefully one of the PowerApps folks can chime in.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that we will need a very easy to implement solution as I am not able to mess with the general configurations of the Sharepoint sides.